# Why is the color of list is not changing in the below html example

Tags: html, css, frontend

I created a small web page using html and css. i tried to change the color of list "a". but it is not working. what might be the problem?

try: i tried to change the color of list **a** using class **color**. but the code is not working.

## html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Adding CSS</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Three Methods of Adding CSS</h1>
  <a href="./inline.html">Inline</a>
  <a href="./internal.html">Internal</a>
  <a href="./external.html">external</a>



  <ol>
    <li class="color" >a</li>
    <li>b</li>
  </ol>
</body>

</html>
```

## css

```
h1 {color: green;}

.color {
    color:red
}
```

expecting :

what i'm expecting is to change the color of the list a using class color but it is not changing. what might be the error?

Comment: Did you put the CSS in [`<style/>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) tag?

Comment: Make the code into a snippet - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example That will include the CSS - I doubt you will stil see the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The code you wrote works as expected, but you did not connect the CSS with HTML.
Add this to your `<head>` of the html or open a `<style>` and put your css in it.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`

Answer (score -1):

your code is working fine. You must include the CSS file if you are using external CSS. And you forgot to add the semicolon after the {color: red} property.